# LightHTTPD - Software caused connection abort

Tags: windows-7, ssl, lighttpd

I have a local LightTPD server running on my windows 7 computer.

I have SSL set up and it works - but every time I request a document from the SSL part of the server I get the following on the logging window:

```
2013-03-17 19:11:05: (connections.c.1721) SSL (error): 5 -1 113 Software caused
connection abort
```

Related `lighthttpd.conf` lines:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":444" {
   ssl.engine    = "enable" 
   ssl.pemfile   = cert_dir + "/server.pem" 
}
```

Do I need to worry about it and is there any way that I can stop it from doing this?

Comment: i recommend to use lighttpd only on a unix - if you need it on your windows development box i'd recommend to run it in a linux vm. apart from that make sure you have the latest version (1.4.32 right now).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It seems that if I juggle the ports around and get it running on ports 80 and 443, the messages do not appear anymore. Weird.